# How to check the protocol with the new Symfony Expression syntax in a TypoScript condition

Tags: symfony, typo3, typoscript

I need to check the protocol with the Symfony Expression Langange in TypoScript conditions.

The old syntax is
`[globalString = IENV:TYPO3_SSL=1]`

But in the documentation, there is no mention of `TYPO3_SSL`.

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Conditions/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with TYPO3 ver.: `9.4` and next, this can be used as a replacement:

`[request.getNormalizedParams().isHttps() == true]`

Here are some more references for migrating TypoScript conditions:

- https://wiki.sebkln.de/doku.php?id=typo3:about:conditions
- https://usetypo3.com/symfony-expression-language-in-typo3.html
- https://www.nitsan.in/blog/all-you-need-to-know-about-typoscript-conditions-with-symfony-expression-language/

Comment: Link to official TYPO3 documentation: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/Conditions/Index.html#request-getnormalizedparams